# Using gtest specific parameters inside the testcase

Tags: c++, googletest

Im using gtest as the test framework for my project and I need to use the following parameter value which is passed as a gtest parameter, inside the test case

`./gtest_bin --gtest_repeat=5`

Currently what I'm doing is, I've created a custom Listener extended from "EmptyTestEventListener" and pass the iteration value to a global variable when the callback to the following function is received as following,

*customListener class*

```
class customListener : public testing::EmptyTestEventListener
{
    customListener(int *iteration) : m_iteration(iteration) {}

    virtual void OnTestIterationStart(const testing::UnitTest& unit_test, int iteration)
    {  
        *m_iteration = iteration;
    }
}
```

*main*

```
int g_iteration;

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);

    if(argc > 1)
        g_array_length = atoi(argv[1]);

    testing::TestEventListeners& listners = testing::UnitTest::GetInstance()->listeners();
    listners.Append(new printers::customListener(&g_iteration));

    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

Is there an easier way to get this gtest parameter value?

If generalized, Is there a way to get any gtest specific parameter value that can used inside a testcase?

Comment: Are `g_iteration` and `g_array_length` the same thing?

Comment: `g_array_length` is totally a separate variable, you can ignore it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **IMPORTANT NOTE**
>   Please use with great care - as this is not documented feature and
>   might be changed (i.e. it might stop working) in next gtest/gmock
>   versions.

You can access any flag by `::testing::GTEST_FLAG(flag_name)` - in your case - `::testing::GTEST_FLAG(repeat)`.

I got this information indirectly from this [manual](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#how-it-works) and by examining gtest.h file.

Comment: Thanks for the info. After you mentioned about the flag I checked the gtest variables. But in the gtest version that I'm currently using gives this facility as the variable - `::testing::FLAGS_<parameter_name>` so in this case, `::testing::FLAGS_gtest_repeat`. So exactly like what you've mentioned in the note

Comment: `GTEST_FLAG` is a macro that is defined as `#define GTEST_FLAG(name) FLAGS_gtest_##name` - so we both are correct - but I believe - my version is a little safer...